# RestFB API: Posting an image to my wall, with a hyper-link gives java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary attachment data cannot be null

Tags: facebook, image, fileinputstream, restfb

**Situation**: I'm trying to post an image to my own wall in Facebook. The image is to be hyper-linked to some given url (google.com for example).

The code snippet is as follows (pretty standard one from the RestFB API). I'm using the latest restfb-1.13:

```
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            FacebookType publishPhotoResponse = facebookClient.publish("me/photos", FacebookType.class,
             BinaryAttachment.with("logo200x200.png", getClass().getResourceAsStream(url)),
             Parameter.with("link", "www.google.com"),
             Parameter.with("message", "Test"));
```

**Problem**: I'm getting an error message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary attachment data cannot be null.

**What I've tried so far**: I've tried obtaining the image from my local harddisk using this code but it gives the same error:

```
            InputStream photoInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(url));
            Image image = ImageIO.read(photoInputStream);

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            FacebookType photo = facebookClient.publish("me/photos" , FacebookType.class,
                    BinaryAttachment.with("logo200.png", photoInputStream),
                    Parameter.with("message", "your message"));
        Link photoLink = facebookClient.fetchObject(photo.getId(), Link.class);
        FacebookType post =  facebookClient.publish("me/feed", FacebookType.class,
                    Parameter.with("message", "your message"),Parameter.with("type", "photo"),
                    Parameter.with("link", photoLink.getLink()));
```

Finally, how to link another Url to the image?

Comment: That endpoint (`/me/photos`) does not take a `link` parameter. You could put the URL into the `message`, but you are not allowed to have your app pre-fill or append to the message, it has to be a 100% user generated (i.e., typed in by the user) – so that would only be (kind of) an option, if you’re only planning to use this yourself. If you want to link the image itself “to” something, then you can not upload it as a photo – then you have to post a link instead, and set the image as thumbnail for that link.

Comment: CBroe, thanks for replying. I checked the restfb documentation, but they haven't mentioned anything about thumbnails.

Comment: You are using the Facebook API, and therefor the Facebook API documentation is the first thing you should consult.

Comment: You should use a debugger, it seems your InputStream is `null`. That's what the Exception says.